# Consuming pure ES2015 libraries with Webpack 2

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, webpack-2

### Context

I've been using a monolithic `src` tree internally and have recently split it into separate smaller libraries for reuse.  Since this is all internal, I have no need for these libraries to produce ES5.  I want our webpack 2 apps to be able to consume pure ES2015 libraries.

### Problem

The problem is, when I produce a pure ES2015 library, my webpack transpiled app fails with:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor RouteConfig cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

The source of this is:

```
import {RouteConfig} from '@acme/ui/config'
```

### Sanity check

For verification that I'm not doing anything obviously wrong, I verified:

1. the library built as ES5 works
2. the app including the library (with the ES2015 preset added to it) via source alias works

### Details

#### Library `.babelrc`

```
{ // produce a pure es2015 build
  "presets": [
    "es2017",
    "es2016",
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-relay-plugin-loader",
    "flow-react-proptypes",
    "transform-flow-strip-types",
    "lodash",
    "transform-runtime"
  ],
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "presets": [
        "react-optimize"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        ["react-remove-properties", {"properties": ["data-test"]}]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

#### Application `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2017",
    "es2016",
    ["es2015", {"modules": false}], // allows webpack2 to interpret ES2015 modules+
    "stage-0", // if omitted, this leaves `export Log from './Log'`
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-relay-plugin-loader",
    "flow-react-proptypes",
    "transform-flow-strip-types",
    "lodash",
    "transform-runtime",
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ],
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "presets": [
        "react-optimize"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        ["react-remove-properties", {"properties": ["data-test"]}]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### TLDR;

- We have many libraries and many apps that are internal and don't need ES5
- I want to author both a library and an app in ES2015+.
- Each library will create a pure ES2015 build for the private npm package.
- I want to take advantage of as much webpack 2 tree shaking/optimization as possible.
- Our library works as an ES5 package
- Our library works as a source alias to the app with the 2015 preset added to it's `.babelrc`
- Source alias usage for all our libraries is not desirable

### Question

What config is needed to get webpack 2 to consume a pure ES2015 library?

Comment: The error itself shouldn't have anything to do with your webpack config. `class` constructors cannot be called as functions. That's what the error is telling you. So you need to fix your code so that `RouteConfig` is called as a constructor (with `new`) not as a function.

Comment: What is your webpack config? If all that stuff is now in `node_modules` it sounds like your ES5 Babel config just isn't being used.

Comment: @FelixKling - as mentioned, the code is verified as working in multiple ways. It also passes eslint and flowtype, so I think you are on the wrong track.  I'm not suggesting it is a webpack config, my thoughts were some misconfiguration of babel for webpack 2.

Comment: @loganfsmyth - [here is a gist of the resolved webpack config](https://gist.github.com/rosskevin/da99def9e7be592d18f54cb321ec0c90) for development.

Comment: What can I say... that's the error you get when a `class` constructor is not called correctly. This error wouldn't necessarily occur in transpiled code since `class`es are converted to ordinary functions. How is `RouteConfig` used? If it is invoked in some third party code, then ESLint and flow wouldn't necessarily catch that.

Comment: @FelixKling it isn't being instantiated at all where it errors.  [Here is a gist excerpt](https://gist.github.com/rosskevin/6b318520dc31bb94e82914ac811bb342).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're excluding the node_modules folder in your babel-loader.  If so, you can try modifying the exclude regex.

ie.

```
test: /\.js$/,
use: [
    'babel-loader'
],
exclude: [/.*node_modules((?!folder_name_here).)*$/]
```